How to make the curve extrude on the X and Y axis
How can I make the curve extrude on the X and Y axis, instead of the mesh extruding on the Z axis.  using the Geometry extrude in the object data properties.



Press CtrlT90 to tilt the vertices 90° or open the N panel and change the Mean Tilt to 90°:


Always learning in this forum, Thanks moonboots!
